# replace number greater than 5 digits in a text

Tags: r, regex, gsub, regex-group, data-masking

```
a <- c("this is a number 9999333333 and i got 12344")
```

How could i replace the number greater than 5 digits with the extra digits being "X"

Expected Output:

```
"this is a number 99993XXXXX and i got 12344"
```

Code i tried:

```
gsub("(.{5}).*", "X", a)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with a PCRE regex:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|(?<!\d)\d{5})\K\d
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O2E9zu/1). Details:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|(?<!\d)\d{5})` - the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) a location not preceded with a digit (`(?<!\d)`) and then any five digits
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\d` - a digit.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/AxkkkG):

```
a <- c("this is a number 9999333333 and i got 12344")
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|(?<!\\d)\\d{5})\\K\\d", "X", a, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "this is a number 99993XXXXX and i got 12344"
```

Comment: Thanks, If i want to replace X after first 2 digits for numbers greater than 5 digits , how could i change it eg: "this is a number 99XXXXXXXX and i got 12344"

Comment: @prog Then use `gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|(?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?=\\d{4}))\\K\\d", "X", a, perl=TRUE)`. The `(?=\d{4})` positive lookahead requires four more digits to appear immediately after the first two.

Answer (score 2):

`gsubfn` in the gsubfn package is like `gsub` except the replacement string can be a function which inputs the capture groups and outputs a replacement to the match.  The function can optionally be expressed in a formula notation as we do here.

The regular expression `(\d{5})` matches and captures 5 digits and `(\d+)` matches and captures the remaining digits.  The two capture groups are fed into the function and are pasted back together except each character in the second is replaced with `X`.  `r"{...}"` is the notation for string literals introduced in R 4.0 which eliminates having to use double backslashes to denote a backslash within a string literal.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn(r"{(\d{5})(\d+)}", ~ paste0(x, gsub(".", "X", y)), a)
## [1] "this is a number 99993XXXXX and i got 12344"
```

If we replace the first argument with the regular expression `r"{(\d{2})(\d{4,})}"` then it will replace all but the first two digits provided there are at least 6 digits.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way, not using `gsub` to *replace numbers greater than 5 digits in a text* is to split the string with `strsplit`, test if there are only digits and combine a `substr` and a `strrep`:

```
paste(lapply(strsplit(a, " ")[[1]], function(x) {
  if(!grepl("\\D", x)) {
    paste0(substr(x, 1, 5), strrep("X", pmax(0, nchar(x)-5)))
  } else {x}}), collapse = " ")
#[1] "this is a number 99993XXXXX and i got 12344"
```

To replace X after first 2 digits for numbers greater than 5 digits:

```
paste(lapply(strsplit(a, " ")[[1]], function(x) {
  if(!grepl("\\D", x) & nchar(x) > 5) {
    paste0(substr(x, 1, 2), strrep("X", pmax(0, nchar(x)-2)))
  } else {x}}), collapse = " ")
#[1] "this is a number 99XXXXXXXX and i got 12344"
```